# Fastest way to loop through GCP project

Tags: python, performance, google-cloud-platform, devops

I am trying to loop through GCP projects, where I have more than 50,000 projects and close to 20,000 buckets. However, what is the best way to make the loop faster? Here is my code below:

```py
for project in projects:
    #print(project)
    project = project['projectId']

    try:
        buckets = client.list_buckets(project=project)
        for bucket in buckets:
            policy = bucket.get_iam_policy()
            print(policy)
            for test in policy:
                if 'name' in test:
                    print("this is just an example")
    except...
```

```
def main():
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
try:
    projects = build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials=Credentials.from_authorized_user_info(info=google.auth.default()[1]), cache_discovery=False).projects().list().execute().get('projects', [])
except DefaultCredentialsError:
    logger.exception("Error getting default credentials")
    return
thread = 25
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=thread) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(get_bucket_policies, project) for project in projects]
    results = []
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        results.extend(future.result())
        logger.info(f"Finished processing {len(results)} of {len(projects)} projects")
for project_id, bucket_name in results:
    print(f"{project_id} - {bucket_name}")
```

Comment: `faster` is not a problem description. What do you want to achieve? Clearly define the objective and problem in your post. The code you have written is sequential. To optimize that code requires understanding the end result(s).

Comment: Please also consider rate limits that GCP imposes on your client. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-rate#redistribution

Comment: @JohnHanley i would like to find the bucket iam policy information from each bucket that that i have so the code right now takes time to run. It takes around 30mins or so to run the whole code, is there any way to make the code faster

Comment: Run the code in parallel.

Comment: @JohnHanley what you mean i haven't done anything like that

Comment: @lisa_rao007 You can consider use `multithread` and `multiprocess` which are simple to achieved in python. If `get_iam_policy` is `api`, the `multithread` will help u. And `multiprocess` mostly not improve in python.

Comment: @JunXiang i added the thread method and still looks like slow

Comment: @JohnHanley or JunXiang any suggestion

Comment: The challenge that you will have is to benchmark the process of listing projects and buckets. Once you know where the time is spent, then you can optimize the design. I am guessing that most of the time is spent waiting for responses from Google APIs. You can overlap tasks while waiting but you cannot speed up Google's management software. Another potential issue is that Google will rate-limit API requests. The number of API calls to fetch details on 50,000 projects and 20,000 buckets will most likely throttle your program with 429 (Too Many Requests) errors.

Comment: Your task is probably best implemented with caching of already fetched data in a database. That way you can refresh data as opposed to fetching 100% each time.